# add_message_files() directory not found in hector messages

Tags: ros, add-message-files, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was trying to build custom message in hector_quadrotor package. For some reason, I cannot catkin_make the packages. Modified packages are all removed and it still cannot solve errors.
Enter catkin_make, it shows:

```
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:91
> (message):   add_message_files()
> directory not found: 
> /home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/msg
> Call Stack (most recent call first):  
> CMakeLists.txt:23 (add_message_files)
```

"CMakeLists.txt" is changed back to original version as below,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(hector_uav_msgs)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED message_generation std_msgs)
add_message_files(
  FILES
  Altimeter.msg
  AttitudeCommand.msg
  Compass.msg
  ControllerState.msg
  HeadingCommand.msg
  HeightCommand.msg
  MotorCommand.msg
  MotorPWM.msg
  MotorStatus.msg
  PositionXYCommand.msg
  RawImu.msg
  RawMagnetic.msg
  RawRC.msg
  RC.msg
  RuddersCommand.msg
  ServoCommand.msg
  Supply.msg
  ThrustCommand.msg
  VelocityXYCommand.msg
  VelocityZCommand.msg
  YawrateCommand.msg
)
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES hector_uav_msgs
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

Any advice on how to solve this error?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213683/add_message_files()-directory-not-found-in-hector-messages/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-14**:
Well, the error states that it is looking for the messages in `/home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/msg`
Where is the `CMakeLists.txt` that you are calling?

The msgs as well as the `CMakeLists.txt` should be in a package.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2015-07-14**:
The `CmakeLists.txt` in `/home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/hector_uav_msgs/`. I don't know how to change its search directories to 'CMakeLists.txt' directory...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-14**:
can you please post the full CMakeLists.txt? You can add the switch `DIRECTORY <dir>` to the `add_message_files` call, but I don't know if this is enough already.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2015-07-14**:
I added the full CMakeList.txt code above. That's the original cmakelist.txt. I don't think it caused the error. Actually, I removed the whole package "hector_quadrotor". And I build a new workspace by "catkin_create_pkg". When I try to build the new workspace, it showed the same error.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2015-07-14**:
it seems that error came from message directory file in ROS root path...

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-15**:
Have you fixed this now? Having the a `msg` directory in the Root of your workspace is probably not a good idea.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2015-07-15**:
well, I was trying to say the error should came from message related files in "/opt/ros/indigo", instead of created workspace.

**Comment by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on 2015-07-15**:
I didn't solve it yet. So, I reinstall the entire ROS...

**Comment by [rushsaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/27069/rushsaker/) on 2016-06-06**:
I've install the latest version of ROS Kinetic & meet the same problem like you. reinstalling the entire ROS, hope i can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> directory not found:
> /home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/src/msg

Your directory structure is most likely messed up. Similar to the issue #q67415. ROS uses a "workspace" concept when building source code with it. I suggest you go through the [basic tutorial set](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) once again (no worries I've gone through them multiple times in the past) to familiarize with the concept.

Particularly with your setting I would assume directory structure including the problematic `msg` folder would look something like (`catkin_ws` can be named anything you like):

```
/home/xiaohao/catkin_ws/src/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/msg
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0